npm-run-all does not work for node 20 and npm 10
npm-run-all scripts which is working fine with Node 14 is not working with node v20.10.0 npm 10.2.5 - is there an alternative for this?
npm-run-all --serial clean
ERROR: npm v10.2.5 is known not to run on Node.js v14.17.3.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: ^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
ERROR:
ERROR: npm v10.2.5 is known not to run on Node.js v14.17.3.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: ^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
ERROR:
/xxxx/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/agent/lib/agents.js:105
    options.lookup ??= this.#options.lookup
                   ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='

any help here?

npm-run-all hasn't been updated in 5 years, so that's not too surprising. Either use https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all2 or find another script runner?

Your dependency upgrade of such a large gap will likely be a poor experience, but a right of passage non-the-less. You can look at install-legacy-peer-deps and another package alternative concurrently.

This is an issue with how your executables are linked in your PATH system variable. I see you're using nvm for your node version management, but something has not been linked correctly. When you type node —v, the executable begins referenced from another directory on your computer; use which node and/or where node, depending on your OS, to locate this / these path. Appending the correct directory path to your systems echo $PATH variable should do the trick. Also, just trying to re-link the executable using nvm is a perfect place to start, which might be a faster method.


Richard, i have npm and node versions correctly along with the path

npm -v
10.2.5
node -v
v20.10.0
echo $PATH
/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin:/usr/local/apache-maven-3.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/apache-maven-3.9.4/bin:/Users/xxx/xxxx/xxxx/node_modules/.bin


Using Markdown will help others read your posts.

So it doesn't look like the issue is with the package here is how the processes are spawned. It looks like there is an option to pass the npm path. const npmPath = options.npmPath || process.env.npm_execpath but then it executes that in another process and streams the io to stdin and stdout. In the context of this script it uses spawn. Take a look here. Let us know how it goes!

I think another possible solution is setting "start": "NODE_PATH=/ur/path/node npm-run-all --serial clean" also if your going to only run one task you should just be running npm run clean

I tried all the above options and none worked, and i found that problem is not with node20, it is in my local env where node14.17.3 comes up even though i uninstalled node14.17.3, searched and removed all symlinks, but somewhere there is a reference to this node14.17.3 which is making it fail.  Same code is working fine on the test env.
